# tree function that check if the value of a node is equal to the two previous nodes' values

Tags: c

I want to make a function that checks from the third node in each path (left or right) if it is equal to the sum of the two previous nodes in the tree.

here is my code but it doesn't work that way :

```
    typedef struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
    } node;
    
    int goldtree(node *root)
    {
        int sumleft=0,sumright=0;
        if (root->left==NULL || root->right ==NULL)
            return 0;
        
        sumleft+=root->data+goldtree(root->left);
        sumright+=root->data+goldtree(root->right);
        if (goldtree(root->right)==sumright || sumleft==goldtree(root->left))
            return 1;
    }
```

and here is an example :

[[image]]

Comment: You need a reference to the last node you visited. For the root, this is null, so check both paths. If you are at a leaf (where both links are null), return true. If none of the links lead to a node where the value is the sum of the current and the previous node, descend to that node. Otherwise, return false. (What happens when the root node is a leaf? The question doesn't specify that, but you should consider that case, too.)

Comment: One issue is that `goldtree` does not always return a value, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry that I understood your problem in a wrong way for the first time! Deleted prev answer :/

So, you want to check the tree is `golden` or not, the rules are following if I am not wrong:

- every current node is the sum of prev two nodes, except for the root node.
- if there is such a path exists from root to leave node, then the tree is golden.

You can change your function like below:

```
int goldtree(node *root, int flag){
    int result = 0;
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
  
    /* we have come up to leave node */
    else if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) return 1;

    else{
        /* we would traverse only the path where child node's value - current node's value is equal to prev node' value */            
        if(root->left != NULL && root->left->data - root->data == flag) {
            result = goldtree(root->left, root->data);
        }

        if(root->right != NULL && root->right->data - root->data == flag){
            result = goldtree(root->right, root->data);
        }
        return result;
     }
  
}
```

Driver function to call `goldtree` is:

```
    goldtree(root, 0);
```

Notes:
Why we are checking node's value before traversing the path is, we would only consider those path where child node's value would be equal to current node + prev node value;

If your path is like below:

```
      1
     /
    2
   /
  3
```

when you are in node `2` you can consider prev two nodes value of child node `3`:

```
3 - 2 == 1 --> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `goldtree()` is implemented in top-down manner, attempting to look down the tree, so that when run on a given node, the values of that node's grandchildren are checked.  This is a viable way to approach the problem, but there are several issues you need to deal with, among them

- each node has up to four grandchildren, and you need to check all of them, and
- you need to be prepared to handle nodes that have fewer than two children and / or fewer than four grandchildren.

With respect to your particular code, you seem to be getting confused about the significance of `goldtree()`'s return value.  It does not make sense to compute sums such as `root->data+goldtree(root->left)`, because `goldtree()` returns a flag (purportedly) representing whether the subtree rooted at its argument node satisfies the condition.  The sum would make sense only if it were returning a node's value.  Even then, however, you need to consider up to *two* node value sums for each child of the current node, and you cannot easily represent that with a single `int`.

Again, you could address those issues to make your function work successfully.  However, I think it would be cleaner to reimplement it in bottom-up fashion, so that each node you reach checks *itself*, in light of the values of its parent and grandparent.  The complication with this is that your node structures do not have parent pointers, so you will need to convey that information via function parameters.  You can do that without changing the signature of `goldtree()` by adding a helper function:

```
int goldtree(node *root) {
    return goldtree_helper(root, NULL, NULL);
}

int goldtree_helper(node *current, node *parent, node *grandparent) {
    /*
     * Left as an exercise:
     *
     * behavior depends in part on whether 'current', 'parent' and / or
     * 'grandparent' is NULL.
     *
     * If this node itself passes the test, then the return value also depends
     * on whether its children do.
     */

     /*
      * Example child check, demonstrating cycling the arguments
      * to convey the correct parent and grandparent:
      */
     int left_is_golden = goldtree_helper(current->left, current, parent);
}
```